# MonoDevelop Compilation & GAC

Tags: windows, build, compilation, monodevelop, gac

I'm a bit confused as to what's happening here.

My understanding is that when an assembly is required at runtime, the runtime will first try to load the assembly from the executing directory (or the directory where the dependant executable is located). After which it will attempt to find the assembly within the GAC.

First of all, I am on Windows.

Now, when I'm compiling my solution is VS, everything works fine (as expected), but when I compile the same solution in MonoDevelop, the compilation stops due to errors pertaining to a missing log4net reference (the exact assembly for which I manually installed into the GAC to avoid this situation).

So, my question is this: Does MonoDevelop look at the GAC at compilation time to determine if an assembly is available, or is there another location in which I need to provide the required assembly?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

From [MonoDevelop site](http://monodevelop.com/FAQ#I_added_an_assembly_to_the_GAC.2c_why_doesn%27t_it_appear_in_the_assemblies_list_when_I_try_to_add_a_reference_in_a_MonoDevelop_project.3f):

> **I added an assembly to the GAC, why doesn't it appear in the assemblies list when I try to add a reference in a MonoDevelop project?**
>
> Bacause MonoDevelop does not look for assemblies in the GAC. On Mac
>   and Linux, MonoDevelop uses pkg-config to locate installed packages
>   and get the list of assemblies that each package provides. A package
>   specifies this list of assemblies in a .pc file which has to be
>   installed in the standard pkg-config directory.
>
> If you are developing a library, MonoDevelop can automatically
>   generate a .pc file for your project (in the project options dialog,
>   select "Linux Deployment Settings", and check the "Generate .pc file"
>   option).
>
> When targetting .NET on Windows, MonoDevelop uses the same
>   AssemblyFolders mechamisn that VS uses.

Comment: I tried adding the assembly into the folder designated by the AssemblyFolders registy, but to no avail. I also tried adding my own custom folder to the AssemblyFolders registry, but, again, no luck. However, in both cases, the assemblies did show up in the "add a reference" window.