# MonoDevelop unable to see System.Web.Mvc3

Tags: linux, mono, monodevelop, gac, pkg-config

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980105/monodevelop-compilation-gac) MonoDevelop uses pkg-config to locate installed packages and get the list of assemblies that each package provides.

So why is this happening?

```
me@my-PC:~$ pkg-config --list-all | grep -i system.web.mvc
system.web.mvc                   System.Web.Mvc - System.Web.Mvc - ASP.NET MVC
system.web.mvc2                  System.Web.Mvc2 - System.Web.Mvc - ASP.NET MVC v2
system.web.mvc3                  System.Web.Mvc3 - System.Web.Mvc - ASP.NET MVC v3
me@my-PC:~$

me@my-PC:~$ cat /usr/lib/pkgconfig/system.web.mvc*
Name: System.Web.Mvc2
Description: System.Web.Mvc - ASP.NET MVC v2
Version: 2.0.0.0
Libs: -r:/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.Mvc/2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Web.Mvc.dll
Name: System.Web.Mvc3
Description: System.Web.Mvc - ASP.NET MVC v3
Version: 3.0.0.0
Libs: -r:/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.Mvc/3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Web.Mvc.dll
Name: System.Web.Mvc
Description: System.Web.Mvc - ASP.NET MVC
Version: 1.0.0.0
Libs: -r:/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.Mvc/1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Web.Mvc.dll
me@my-PC:~$
```

[image]

Comment: Can you simply add the assembly manually, like you can in Visual Studio?  Looks like there's a tab there you can use for that purpose.

Comment: Yes I can but I'd like to solve this issue.

Comment: Not particularly interesting, seeing as you already have a workaround.  This problem has happened to me several times over the years, and the solution is always the same: add it manually, and get on with life.